# Class to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a C# class as follows :

```
class CoverageInfo {
    public string className;
    public int blocksCovered;
    public int blocksNotCovered;

    public CoverageInfo(string className, int blocksCovered, int blocksNotCovered) 
    {
        this.className = className;
        this.blocksCovered = blocksCovered;
        this.blocksNotCovered = blocksNotCovered;
    }
}
```

And, I have a List, ModuleName, BlocksCovered/BlocksNotCovered variable.
Out of those information, I need to create an XML file as follows.

```
<Coverage>
  <Module>
    <ModuleName>hello.exe</ModuleName>
    <BlocksCovered>5</BlocksCovered>
    <BlocksNotCovered>5</BlocksNotCovered>
    <Class>
       <ClassName>Fpga::hello</ClassName>
       <BlockCovered>5</BlocksCovered>
       <BlocksNotCovered>2</BlocksNotCovered>
    </Class>
    <Class>
        ...
    </Class>
  </Totalcoverage>
</Coverage>
```

How can I do that with C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With such a simple case I would use the `XmlSerializer` with XML serialization attributes.

A good tutorial is provided here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/GameCatalog.aspx

I would urge you to use properties instead of members as you'll be more flexible in implementing hooks or differentiate get/set access rights in the future. (However the latter has to remain public if you still want to use XML attributes or you'll have to switch to implementing `IXmlSerializable`.)

The code then would look like this in your case:

```
class CoverageInfo {
    [XmlElement("ClassName")]
    public string className;
    [XmlElement("BlockCovered")]
    public int blocksCovered;
    [XmlElement("BlocksNotCovered")]
    public int blocksNotCovered;

    ....
}
```

The job is then done by the `XmlSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xsd.exe** (provided with Visual Studio) to generate classes from an xml file (if you have the xsd file, it would be even better). The command is:

```
xsd <path to xsd or xml> /c /o:<path where the cs file is saved>
```

Then, just create the list of objects you want saved as an xml and do something similar to this:

```
GetEntityXml(coverageInfo).Save(@"D:\out.xml");
```

where coverageInfo is a `List<CoverageInfo>` and GetEntityXml<sup>1</sup> is:

```
public XmlDocument GetEntityXml<T>(List<T> listToSave)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
    using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute("Whatever you need"));
        ser.Serialize(writer, listToSave);
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

<sup>1</sup> [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237683/xml-serialization-of-listt-xml-root/1334483#1334483) where credit is due.