# XML serialization of list

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am serializing an object to XML.  I have something like this:

```
Class A
{
   public string propertyA1  { get; set; }
   public List<B> bList { get; set; }
}

Class B
{
   public string num {get; set;}
   public string propertyB1  { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize it to XML, I want it to look like this:

```
<A>
  <propertyA1>someVal</propertyA1> 
  <B num=1>
     <propertyB1>someVal</propertyB1> 
  </B>
  <B num=2>
     <propertyB1>someVal</propertyB1> 
  </B>
</A>
```

But, instead it looks like this:

```
<A>
  <propertyA1>someVal</propertyA1> 
  <bList>
     <B num=1>
        <propertyB1>someVal</propertyB1> 
     </B>
     <B num=2>
        <propertyB1>someVal</propertyB1> 
     </B>
  </bList>
</A>
```

Any idea how to get rid of the **bList** in the output?  I can provide more sample code if needed

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the attribute `[XmlElement]` to treat the collection as a flat list of elements:

```
Class A
{
   public string propertyA1  { get; set; }
   [XmlElement("B")]
   public List<B> bList { get; set; }
}
```

for more info click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Excellent, simple and straightforward - was trying using [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237683/xml-serialization-of-listt-xml-root) but your solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try XmlArrayItemAttribute. Please refer below links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.71).aspx