# XmlRoot gets overwritten when using System.Xml.Serialization Serializing Generic class

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization, root-element

Dear StackOverflow lovers,

I'm having my XmlRoot overwritten whenever I try to serialize a object from a generic class.

=> I get as XmlRoot: classname + _x0060_1 (by the way, there is a 1 because there is only one Type parameters given, in other word it could be any number of type parameter needed)

Even if I use

```
[XmlRoot("BaseSyncOneWayInput")]
```

or even

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = typeof(T).Name;
```

Here is a .NET Fiddle to reproduce to bug: https://dotnetfiddle.net/X9fRkA

Comment: Should find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1237827/1462295 -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/vEm141

Comment: thanks! I c'ant wait to try this back at work tomorow

Comment: If you use that answer, you should cache the `XmlSerializer` to avoid a memory leak as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897145/memory-leak-using-streamreader-and-xmlserializer).

Comment: @dbc is that still the case? It appears the constructor now implements a cache: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/90b323fe52bec428fe4bd5f007e9ead6b265d553/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs (e.g. line 184)

Comment: Thank you @BurnsBA that does the trick

Comment: @BurnsBA - it's still [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-2.0#Remarks) to be true even in .Net core 2.0:  *If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance.  ... you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable*.

Comment: isn't what the using is for ? to dispose

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue.  I added a test class to your code and modified you main() method to use class.  Results work.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyListClass[] myListClass = new MyListClass[3];
            Console.WriteLine(Pull<string>("","",myListClass));
        }
    }
    public class MyListClass
    {
        string myProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Me neither... :D u use the fiddle that has been edited from the original fiddle, If you change line 34 by 
`attr.XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name);`
instead of
`//attr.XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("BaseSyncOneWayInput");`

you'll get a nice : `</BaseSyncOneWayInput_x0060_1>` xml tag

Comment: It is hard to hit a moving target.

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: When you keep on editing the posting (the moving target), the responses/answers don't always reflect the latest issue.